# How to turn one goroutine into multiple goroutines without requiring a lock?

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, goroutine, channel

We have a HostPinger function which is meant to be launched as one goroutine(from `Main`) and is in charge of monitoring the health of a list of hosts it is initialized with using a list of clients. The code is below:

```
package server

var getHostHealthChan = make(chan chan bool)
var addHostChan = make(chan string)
var removeHostChan = make(chan string)

func GetHostsHealth() []bool {
    hostHealthList := make(chan bool)
    getHostHealthChan <- hostHealthList
    healthList := make([]bool, 0, 10)
    for health := range hostHealthList {
        healthList = append(healthList, health)
    }
    return healthList
}

func AddHost(host string) {
    addHostChan <- host
}

func RemoveHost(host string) {
    removeHostChan <- host
}

func HostPinger(hosts []string, clients []Client) {
    for {
        select {
        case req := <-getHostHealthChan:
            for i, host := range hosts {
                req <- clients[i].GetHostHealth(host)
            }
        case host := <-addHostChan:
            hosts = append(hosts, host)
            // some logic
        case host := <-removeHostChan:
            // some other logic to remove host
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with our current implementation is that adding/removing/checking any host(s) blocks the entire goroutine, so we end up with pretty bad concurrency as a result. Because `GetHostsHealth` turned out to be a pretty frequent call, we are seeing some performance problems. What's a good way to refactor this code into a form that supports higher concurrency?

The first thing that comes into mind is to launch one goroutine per host and to use a map to maintain a mapping between host name and host goroutine channel like this:

```
var hostChanMap = make(map[string]chan Op) // this map needs to be protected by lock whenever host add/remove occurs

func HostPinger(hosts []string, clients []Client) {
    for host := range hosts {
        currChan := make(chan Op)
        go HostPingerForHost(currChannel chan Op) {
            // host pinger code
        }(currChan)
        hostChanMap[host] = currChan 
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the add and remove host part would then still need to be synchronized using a lock.

Is there a good solution to this problem where we can have different host health check requests not interfere with each other? Preferably where we don't need to synchronize access to some kind of map?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, `GetHostHealth` sends a request to `HostPinger`, which iterates through all the hosts and call `client.GetHostHealth(host)` for each host, and then returns the result via a channel. There is no concurrency here, everything happens sequentially one after the other. This is no better than calling `client.GetHostHealth(host)` for each host sequentially. The code is also somewhat broken, because `GetHostHealth` gets a `host` argument which is never used, but instead returns a host health slice containing all bools. `HostPinger` is to keep a list of hosts, but this list is unknown to the caller.

What you can do is to call `client.GetHostHealth(host)` concurrently. For this, you'll need a separate goroutine for each host.

```
func GetHostsHealth(hosts []string, clients []Client) []bool {
     healthList := make([]bool, len(hosts))
     wg:sync.WaitGroup{}
     for i:=range hosts {
         i:=i
         wg.Add(1)
         go func() {
              defer wg.Done()
              healthList[i]=clients[i].GetHostHealth(hosts[i])
         }()
     }
     wg.Wait()
     return healthList
}
```

There is no need for a separate goroutine that gets requests via a channel.

You need to keep a list of hosts and their corresponding clients. This is something you already seem to be doing. Just make sure when you call this function, some other goroutine does not try to add/remove items to those.

If maintaining a dynamic list of hosts is at the core of the problem, you can modify what you have to incorporate what I suggested:

```
type HostInfo struct {
   host string
   client Client
}


func HostPinger() {
   hosts:=make(map[string]HostInfo) 
   for {
      select {
         case hostInfo:=<-addHost: // chan HostInfo
            hosts[hostInfo.host]=hostInfo
         case host:=<-removeHost: // chan string
            delete(hosts,host)
         case ret:=<-getHostHealth: // chan chan []bool
            hostList:=make([]string,0,len(hosts))
            clientList:=make([]Client,0,len(hosts))
            for k,v:=range hosts {
               hostList=append(hostList,k)
               clientList=append(clientList,v.cient)
            }
            go func() {
                ret <-GetHostsHealth(hostList,clientList)
             }()
      }     
   }
}
```

This `HostPinger` runs in a separate goroutine, handles host add/remove requests as well as ping requests asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I appreciate it! What if the add/remove operations happen very frequently and we do want to avoid those operations blocking each other as well as the `GetHostsHealth` ? I see that your solution for launching separate goroutines inside `HostPinger` in the `case ret:=<-getHostHealth` will still face this problem?

Comment: Because there is a single goroutine managing the map, there is no locking. All three select cases are non-blocking operations. The ping actually happens asynchronously in a separate goroutine, so the other cases will not be blocked.

Comment: I think the for select loops actually enforce blocking behavior by allowing only one out of the three cases to proceed at a time though

Comment: The select statement will block until at least one of the cases are available. When that happens, the case will execute quickly and go back to select again. So the duration select statement can block an incoming request is limited to the excution time of each of its cases. None of the cases in that select statement will block.